# Git cherry-pick not working as expected

Tags: git, github

This is my problem.
I forked a repo on GitHub. When there were updates on the repo, I used PR (changing base) to update my fork. So my fork showed

```
This branch is xx commits ahead of xxx/xxx
```

Then I changed some files on my fork. When I try to send to PR, it includes all unnecessary commits. (as a result of PRs I made to update my fork). So I used cherry-pick to take only the last commit with a new branch. My git commands for that were(branch-2 is where I added the commit):

```
$ git branch feature origin/branch-2
$ git checkout feature
$ git cherry-pick branch-2
```

But then it picks the wrong commit(some old commit). Is there anything wrong in the commands?

So I tried to pick by SHA. Then it gives `fatal: bad object xxxx`. I read that it is because my commit is corrupt.

I want to clean my fork so the message `This branch is xx commits ahead of xxx/xxx` goes away. I can later add the last commit if this can be done.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the message, "This branch is xx commits ahead of xxx/xxx", all you need to do is remove your remote tracking branch xxx/xxx:

```
git branch -d -r xxx/xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You did a cherry pick on a branch and not on a single commit

```
git cherry-pick branch-2
```

#### What happens?

git translated the `branch-2` to the commit that the branch is pointing to and used it as the commit to pick.

#### `git cherry-pick master`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit with this change.

---

> want to clean my fork so the message This branch is xx commits ahead of xxx/xxx goes away. I can later add the last commit if this can be done.

```
# Discard the last X commits which your branch is ahead of
git reset HEAD~X
```